# Name of this type of inheritance semantic

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
public class _base 
{ 
    protected int x = 5;
    protected int GetX(_base b) { return b.x; }
}


public class _derived : _base 
{ 
    public int Foo()
    {
        var b = new _base();
        //return b.x;  // <-- this would be illegal
        return GetX(b); // <-- This works and does exactly the same as the line above
    }
}
```

(Please don't change code. It is working and shows the problem.)

The error is

```
Cannot access protected member '_base.x' via a qualifier of type '_base'; the qualifier must be of type '_derived' (or derived from it)
```

Note that because b is of type _base and we are not in base we cannot access it's protected members. I imagine the reason is because _base might be of some other derived type and hence it is not protecting the code but that's not the point. What I'm doing is creating a work around for the above problem using the extra protected methods. This gives me the behavior I want and the protection I want. I wish there were a keyword that allows this kinda access but there isn't. What I'm interested in is if this "pattern" has a name.

(I'm using protected because internal allows anyone in the same assembly access)

Comment: Looks similar to a class cracker. There is the internal scope in .net too.

Comment: Note I think what you are doing here is a bad idea. There are better ways of designing your class hierarchy to avoid this kind of need.

Comment: Explain how one can achieve this! There is no keyword in C# that allows this. Internal and friend give way to much access. Protected doesn't give enough. Because I only want to access the protected members of instances of the class INSIDE the class I don't think there is a way to do it using standard oop techniques. (interfaces are all about public access and I that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid)

Comment: The example code does not any sense from a C# point of view. Also I did not mean to upvote the above comment :(

Comment: does not make any sense from C# point of view? Huh? It had a few mistakes(didn't derive from base and used base which is a keyword) but other than that it is perfectly valid C# code.

Comment: I'm confused.  In the example the derived class *does* have access to x, even in other instances of the class.  By marking it as protected, you are implying sub classes are able to use the field.  If not you would mark it as private.  So, what is the actual question?

Comment: Why is there an instance of `derived` within `derived`? Is this 'dual state' intentional?

Comment: I'm sorry, people are changing the code. The code does represent the idea BUT I do not need the class B. What is shown is cross-class access but I only need ancestor access. So in the code treat class B as if it were class A and all instances created.

Comment: If you keep on changing the example code, no one will understand what you are trying to explain/do.

Comment: @Simon: No, Class A cannot class instances of A(or B) in the class. It can only access class members and not instance members. I want to be able to access instance members of A.

Comment: @Leppie: I'm NOT CHANGING IT! Anyways, I've explained it enough. It's not complicated. If you don't get it by now you never will.

Comment: Okay, just saw your edits.  So you're using the protection level to break encapsulation.  I'd say this is more of an anti-pattern, actually.

Comment: It does break it somewhat but not as bad as internal or friend(which wouldn't be too bad but it's not in C#).

Comment: @AstractDissonance, sorry, I was responding to the version of the question when `_derived` contained another instance of `_derived`, not `_base`.  In the current form you are correct in saying that it isn't possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally this sort of access is not allowed because the access modifiers work on classes(as meta access attributes). In your derived class, an instance of your base class has no class relation to the derived class. Here we are mixing instances and classes. The protected keyword offers only access to derived classes but from any instance(even if in a derived class).

It's obviously a deficit in the language but since 99.9% of the time it is not used it is not needed.  In any case there is no keyword in C# that will offer what you want.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Rewriting this answer since the question has been rewritten.

I'm unaware of any name for the pattern you've illustrated.

As you conjecture, the reason it is illegal to access the field is because we don't know that the instance b is an instance of _derived. "protected" access means that _derived is only allowed to access protected members of **instances of _derived**; it is not allowed access to protected members of instances of "SomeOtherType" that is also derived from _base.

Now, if the question really is "is there any way to get *direct* access to the member x from *every* derived class through *any* instance?" then yes. You reject the obvious solution of making it internal. (*) There is another way. Do this:

```
abstract class B
{
    private B() {}
    private int x;
    private class D1 : B { }
    private class D2 : B { }
    public static B MakeD1() { return new D1(); } 
    public static B MakeD2() { return new D2(); }
}
```

Now methods of B and methods of derived classes D1 and D2 are all capable of accessing `this.x` directly, but methods of no other types are capable of doing so. There are no other derived types other than D1 and D2; there cannot be because the only constructor of B is private. And there cannot be any instances of B that are not D1 or D2 because it is abstract.

---

(*) Remember, if you make it internal then the only people you have to worry about accessing your member are your *coworkers*. Putting the smack down on them in code review if they do something abusive to the member is a perfectly acceptable solution around here.

Comment: The original code I posted works just fine in C#. Some one keeps changing it. You USE the derived class to pass the instance of the member you want to access. It works fine.

Comment: @abstract - Why don't you edit your question to fix your code?  If you want feedback, then having the incorrect code in the question isn't going to help.

Comment: Heh, So whats the point of even having D1 and D2 then? In my case I actually want to expose D1 and B and not just B. I simply do not want B instantiated(you sort of have it backwards). Also I'm not talking about the access levels of the classes(they are all public) but that of members of those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

Basically you control who has access to the members via accessors ("setters" and "getters"). How the underlying data is layed out remains hidden to the user.

Think of this:

If you would like to rename your X variable (for whatever reasons) in your base class, but there exists 100 classes derived from that base class who accessed it directly.

You would break that code.

```
class derived
{
  void DoSomething() { x += 1; } // x renamed, doesn't compile anymore
}
```

Now, with encapsulation, since x cannot accessed directly, we got accessors:

```
class derived
{
  void DoSomething() { SetX(GetX() + 1); } // No prob!
}
```

Comment: Read what he is doing again - it is kind of a way of defeating encapsulation.

Comment: The renaming is a non-issue, Visual Studio will rename any uses of `x` when you rename it (using the refactoring tools).  Also, chances are if you rename `x` you're going to rename `GetX()` as well...

Comment: True for a single project. Not true if the user is building a library or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean. Do not create base class' instances in methods. It gets created by the constructor. Reference base class members either using only the member name or you case precede it with the [base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) keyword.

In the above example you would use it as follows:

```
class A : _base { 
     void Foo() {
         x = 10; //or base.x = 10;
         SetX(10); //or base.SetX(10);
         Console.WriteLine(GetX()); //or base.GetX()
     }
}
```

Moreover you may be interested in [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) construct which is a nice syntactic sugar for java's ugly getX and setX pattern.